# Remote portlet access from Liferay

Tags: gwt, liferay, portlet

Is it possible to access portlet hosted by a tomcat on a server X from a Liferay Portal hosted on another server Y ? And how to do this with context sharing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A *portlet* is hosted in a *portlet container*, e.g. Liferay (your tag) which might be hosted on tomcat. Including a portlet from portal X into portal Y (both running on tomcat, but also on anything else) is easy: Look up WSRP (Web Services for Remote Portlets), this is how it's done.

I doubt though that your question is about this. And I'm completely clueless wrt your gwt tag. A portlet can address any resources that are hosted on another server - after all it's generating just HTML content. The URLs for `<script src="xxx"/>` or `<img src="xxx"/>` are irrelevant for the portal. It might be hard to maintain though.

My gut feeling says that you're asking for an overcomplicated solution to a simple problem. But as you don't state the underlying problem, it's hard to find a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

GWT tag is because I have to convert GWT apps to portlets. Next the portlets must be deployed on a Liferay portal hosted on a Tomcat server, And those apps are basically hosted on differents servers, as I said. So I would like to use them remotely, from a distance. The best solution for me would be to link portlet hosted with the portal directly to the GWT apps... Is there any way to do this?